# Is it possible to dynamically change the name of a read Fortran namelist?

Tags: fortran

I would like to do something like:

(in pseudo code)

```
For all x in my_namelist_list
  Read(unit_number,nml=x)
  ...
  some other operations
  ... 
end
```

What is the type of a namelist? Is it possible to pass it as an argument?

```
subroutine generic_reading_of_namelist(namelist_argument)
```

Does someone knows any workaround solution to manipulate many name lists all together?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your answer.

Comment: You don't have to thank in comments, just accept the answer. This is the local way to say thanks if the answer solves or explains the problem correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: namelist has no type because it is a statement, not a variable declaration. This means its use is quite limited: only as the `nml =` argument to I/O operations.

It is also a very old feature, as discussed [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/278777#comment-1466075), whose functionality has changed little since its introduction.

So, what is most straightforward depends on what exactly you want to do. You could try to use one namelist for multiple purposes, for example, or design your own input file format for which you have a custom reading routine.

*Edit:*

Suppose you have an abstract type and some extensions in several modules:

```
module absTypeMod
  implicit none

  type, abstract :: absType
    integer :: i = 0
  contains
    procedure(info), pass(this), public, deferred :: info
  end type

  abstract interface
    subroutine info(this)
      import :: absType
      class(absType), intent(in) :: this
    end subroutine
  end interface
end module

module typeAMod
  use absTypeMod
  implicit none

  type, extends(absType) :: typeA
    private
    integer :: j = 1
  contains
    procedure :: info => info_A
  end type
contains
  subroutine info_A(this)
    class(typeA), intent(in) :: this
    print*, 'i:', this%i, 'j:', this%j
  end subroutine
end module

module typeBMod
  use absTypeMod
  implicit none

  type, extends(absType) :: typeB
    private
    real :: k = 2.0
  contains
    procedure :: info => info_B
  end type
contains
  subroutine info_B(this)
    class(typeB), intent(in) :: this
    print*, 'i: ', this%i, ' k: ', this%k
  end subroutine
end module
```

You can then make a factory module, which provides the logic for instantiating the concrete extensions based on some input. An example:

```
module factoryMod
  use typeAMod
  use typeBMod
  private

  public :: absType, factory

contains
  subroutine factory(t, switch)
    class(absType), allocatable, intent(out) :: t
    character(*), intent(in) :: switch

    select case(switch)
      case('A')
        allocate(typeA :: t)
      case('B')
        allocate(typeB :: t)
    end select
  end subroutine
end module
```

And use it in a test program:

```
program test
  use factoryMod
  implicit none

  class(absType), allocatable :: foo

  call factory(foo, 'A')
  call foo%info()          ! Output: i: 0 j: 1

  call factory(foo, 'B')
  call foo%info()          ! Output: i: 0 k: 2.000000
end program
```

You can make this as fancy as you wish. I use here a simple string to select the actual type to allocate in `factory`, but I've also used an implementation where I pass the `iunit` of a connected input namelist file to the factory. In that case, the factory can use this file not only to determine the type to create, but also to perform a further type-specific setup, whether in the factory itself or in some kind of type-bound initialisation routine (using the same input file).

Also note that this example factory is a subroutine and not a function, since the assignment `foo = factory('A')` is not allowed in Fortran 2003. It is no longer prohibited by F2008, but support is currently not universal.

Comment: I could give better suggestions, but you would need to provide some more information in your question.

Comment: Namelists were added in the Fortran 90 standard, so I would not call them a "very old feature" such as arithmetic IF, COMMON BLOCK, or other delicacies.

Comment: @Fortranner they were standardized in Fortran 90 but they were a vendor extension long before that (I can find references of its use back to FORTRAN IV (1961) and you can find plenty of vendors supporting in their F77 documentation).

Comment: Here are some details about the problem I tried to solve using namelist: I am using the new Object Oriented features of Fortran to program a polymorphic object having the abstract attribute. All realizations of this abstract object have different parameters which are conveniently imported through different namelists. I want to implement an automatic mechanism to select the realization of the object at runtime. It could be done by simply putting the right namelist in the input file. After, I would parse the input file and allocate the abstract object to the appropriate realization.

Comment: @jvtrudel: Sorry, your comment escaped my attention. What I think you're asking for is a factory procedure; I'll write up a short example of how I have done this in the past in Fortran.